# Dynamic multilevel menu in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

i have a table name called menuitems,roles2menu.i fetched group of menu_id,menu_sub_id,menu_child_id in one column, by writing union clause select query.Now i have the values of menu_id,menu_sub_id,menu_child_id.With these values,i want to display multilevel menu in php(in ul and li tag)

i queried and output result is
Menuids  MenuName
500      Transaction
600      Administrator
700      Reports
501      Stock(MENU_SUB_ID)
502      Sales(MENU_SUB_ID)
i have all(menu_id,menu_sub_id,menu_child_id) in above one column i.e.,Menuids.
How to compare these id's in front page php.

Comment: Then go and create it, and if you face any problems with your code, then show us the code and tell us what the problem is. We always want to help, but in order to get help on StackOverflow you need to show us your own attempt on creating this.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Due to not proper information, i will show you the way of creating multiple menus with UL LI structure.

Please have a look the steps.

1) Table structure of my table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `menu_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 if menu is root level or menuid if this is child on any menu',
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0 for disabled menu or 1 for enabled menu',
  PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=37 ;
```

2) dump some data inside the table.

```
INSERT INTO `menu` (`menu_id`, `menu_name`, `parent_id`, `link`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'Home', 0, '#home', '1'),
(2, 'Web development', 0, '#web-dev', '1'),
(3, 'WordPress Development', 0, '#wp-dev', '1'),
(4, 'About w3school.info', 0, '#w3school-info', '1'),
(5, 'AWS ADMIN', 2, '#', '1'),
(6, 'PHP', 2, '#', '1'),
(7, 'Javascript', 2, '#', '1'),
(8, 'Elastic Ip', 5, '#electic-ip', '1'),
(9, 'Load balacing', 5, '#load-balancing', '1'),
(10, 'Cluster Indexes', 5, '#cluster-indexes', '1'),
(11, 'Rds Db setup', 5, '#rds-db', '1'),
(12, 'Framework Development', 6, '#', '1'),
(13, 'Ecommerce Development', 6, '#', '1'),
(14, 'Cms Development', 6, '#', '1'),
(21, 'News & Media', 6, '#', '1'),
(22, 'Codeigniter', 12, '#codeigniter', '1'),
(23, 'Cake', 12, '#cake-dev', '1'),
(24, 'Opencart', 13, '#opencart', '1'),
(25, 'Magento', 13, '#magento', '1'),
(26, 'Wordpress', 14, '#wordpress-dev', '1'),
(27, 'Joomla', 14, '#joomla-dev', '1'),
(28, 'Drupal', 14, '#drupal-dev', '1'),
(29, 'Ajax', 7, '#ajax-dev', '1'),
(30, 'Jquery', 7, '#jquery-dev', '1'),
(31, 'Themes', 3, '#theme-dev', '1'),
(32, 'Plugins', 3, '#plugin-dev', '1'),
(33, 'Custom Post Types', 3, '#', '1'),
(34, 'Options', 3, '#wp-options', '1'),
(35, 'Testimonials', 33, '#testimonial-dev', '1'),
(36, 'Portfolios', 33, '#portfolio-dev', '1');
```

3) Php function which help you to get recursive menu.

```
function get_menu_tree($parent_id) 
{
    global $con;
    $menu = "";
    $sqlquery = " SELECT * FROM menu where status='1' and parent_id='" .$parent_id . "' ";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sqlquery);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
           $menu .="<li><a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['menu_name']."</a>";

           $menu .= "<ul>".get_menu_tree($row['menu_id'])."</ul>"; //call  recursively

           $menu .= "</li>";

    }

    return $menu;
}
```

4) Menu which need to print via this function.

```
<ul class="main-navigation">
<?php echo get_menu_tree(0);//start from root menus having parent id 0 ?>
</ul>
```